# What is "Full constraint" in database theory field?

Tags: database, dependencies, constraints, terminology

What does "full constraint" mean? Its used in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is actually a generally used term. The only definition seems to be further down on the very same page, defined by contrast with "embedded constraint" (for which I can't find definitions anywhere):

> **full constraint**:
>   A constraint which expresses something about all attributes in a database. (In contrast to an embedded constraint.)

In terms of the example given in the article (two multivalued dependencies `course -> book` and `course -> lecturer`), the constraint is "full" in the sense that for *every* `book` that appears in the table, there must be *all* records `(course, book, lecturer)` that are required by the each `course -> lecturer` dependencies, and similarly for every `lecturer`.